# netlogo: comparing attributes of breeds?

Tags: netlogo

In my model i've got two different breeds as following:

```
breeds [sheeps sheep]
breeds [wolves wolf]
```

and each of these has a particular size which changes when they "eat" a patch.
I have another function which checks whether a sheep is in the patch ahead of a wolf and then makes the wolf eat the sheep.
Now wolves should only be able to eat sheep when wolves are two times bigger than the sheep. I've tried to following:

```
to catch-sheep
    ask wolves[
        if any? sheeps-on patch-ahead 1 [
        let prey sheeps-on patch-ahead 1 
        if [ size ] of wolves > [ size ] of prey ) [
        ask [ prey [ die ]]
        ]
      ]
end
```

But this obviously doesn't work and i can't find a solution to how i can easily compare these sizes.
I've also tried to define breeds-own size variables but i had even more trouble to then define their actual size which is seen in plot.

I'd be grateful for any help and i hope this is not a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few issues with your code.
First,
`[size] of wolves` and `[ size ] of prey` reports a list of sizes. so, you can't compare two lists with an inequality sign.

Second, `[ size ] of wolves > [ size ] of prey`, you're comparing all the wolves against all the prey of 1 particular wolf. Instead, you need to use `myself` for the asking wolf to get 1 size. Instead, just ask the prey with their size smaller than myself's size to die.

Below is a correct solution. Essentially, you ask the wolves to determine who their prey is. If there are any prey, then kill the prey whose size is less than the size of the asking wolf (myself).

```
to catch-sheep
    ask wolves[
      let prey sheeps-on patch-ahead 1 
      ask prey with [size < [size] of myself] [die]
    ]
end
```